# Etymology of type cast

Tags: etymology

What is the etymology of cast in the sense of type cast in programming languages?

I found nothing suitable in [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cast).

Comment: Interesting question I think it must be from the OED's sense 49: "IX. To cast (molten) metal; to found. Now one of the most used literal senses.
†49. To throw (anything plastic or fluid) into a particular shape. Obs. in general sense."

Comment: I think **3a** from your link works well: "to dispose or arrange into parts or into a suitable form or order". Casting a type to another type means that you arrange the data into a (more) suitable form (type or class).

Comment: References are wanting for the current answers. This happened in recent memory, a definitive answer should be possible. If it's so trivial that it barely needed explanation and thus lacks writing about it, I'm affraid I don't see it, as the current answers are rather divergent.

Answer (score 5):

To *cast* something is (among some other senses) to make it to fit a particular shape (using a mould) or to have someone play a particular rôle.

*Cast* in computing uses these senses metaphorically in either changing an objects type or treating an object of one type as being of another type. It can then be seen as fitting a particular mould, or playing a particular rôle. (Neither sense is the single source of the metaphor, it worked both ways from the beginning).

*Typecast* in all its senses comes from *type* + *cast*. Since the sort of *casting* one has in programming deals with *types* it follows from the above naturally.

Answer (score 1):

Since we haven't found any authoritative etymology of the programming term, we have to guess where it came from. I would guess, given programmers' love of puns and joke terms, that "cast" came after the term "type", and resulted from "typecast". Whether that was based on the printer's definition or the actor's definition may be unknowable.

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard it explicitly called "type casting" but phrases like "type conversion" or "type coercion" seem fairly common, so yeah.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the term is used in programming languages, but I'm guessing that it's probably something like this (from The Free Dictionary):

2. typecast - identify as belonging to a certain type

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/typecast

Supposedly, a play on actual *cast* (molded to exact specifications) *type* (the individual molded letters which were assembled into words in a printing press.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/typecast